# Circuit breaker automatic switcher

Tags: arduino, mechanical, circuit-breaker

I have a circuit breaker for my house as this one: [image: circuit breaker]

Each time we turn on 3 ACs , the breaker turns the current off and I have to lift the circuit breaker switch which is far down stairs in my basement. I need a mechanism to lift the lever automatically when electricity goes off. I can't change the circuit breaker, so I am thinking of a attaching motor,battery, and an arduino board to get my job done. Do you have any better ways to lift the switch ?

Comment: It sounds like you need to move one of the A/C units to a different circuit, not build some breaker-resetter contraption.

Comment: Agree with ThreePhaseEel.  Your 3 ACs probably have induction motors that run synchronous to the 60 Hz line frequency.  They have a huge inrush when they start and that total inrush exceeds the safe limit on your circuit.  Newer high end heat pumps avoid this problem with brushless DC motors similar to stepper motors that can be slowly brought to speed, avoiding the inrush, and then adjusted up or down to precisely match the load.

Comment: You need an electrician to look into this. Dodgy workarounds are exactly that. You may be able to change to a C or D curve breaker or this may be too much of a load already, which needs to be looked into.

Comment: If your picture is right that is a 6A breaker, normally used on lighting circuits. You need to get an electrician to check the wiring used on the AC circuit, and if the wiring is adequate fit a 16A breaker. Failing that, get the electrician to upgrade the wiring so it can take 16A. Do not implement a self resetting circuit breaker, you are almost certainly breaking some law.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to put 20 pounds of crap into a 10 pound bag.  The solution is to get a bigger bag or put less stuff into it, not a way to automatically pick up the stuff that falls off and pile it on top again.

The breaker is popping for a reason, which is that you are trying to draw too much current.  Don't do that.  Run less air conditioners at a time, run them on different circuits, or get the wiring upgraded to handle the current you want to draw.

What you are doing is defeating a important safety system of your house.  Not only is that stupid in itself, but almost certainly illegal, and a legitimate reason for the insurance company not to pay when your house burns down.  You may even be liable for damage to others' property when that happens.  Bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

### Solve the problem and not the symptoms

> I need a mechanism to lift the lever automatically when electricity goes off.

This would be ill-advised as your automatic reset system would not be able to discriminate between a nuisance trip and a serious fault. You do not want an auto-reset in the event of, for example, motor winding breakdown as this may cause overheating and fire.

Another factor is that MCBs are not intended to be used for frequent switching as you propose. This may affect reliability of the device and, possibly, compromise the protection it affords.

The right solution is to design the circuit and protection properly:

- Get the ratings for your loads.
- Add them up.
- Check the wiring is suitably rated. If the wiring is not rated for the load then you must reduce the load.
- Replace the circuit breaker with the correct type. You *might* be able to solve the problem with a motor-rated breaker which have a slower response time to cater for motor startup. This decision has to be made by someone technically competent.

If you fail at any of these steps then you need to move one unit onto a separate circuit or do some rewiring.

**To be clear: you can not replace the breaker with a unit of higher rating without a full assessment of the circuit it is protecting. Your solution must comply with local electrical regulations.**

---

### B, C and D type circuit breakers

[image]

*Figure 1. B, C and D type MCB characteristic curves. Source: [Study Electrical](http://www.studyelectrical.com/2014/07/miniature-circuit-breakers-mcb-types-characteristic-curves.html).*

> The classification of Type B, C or D is based on fault current rating at which magnetic operation occurs to provide short time protection (typically less than 100ms) against short circuits. It is important that equipment having high inrush currents should not cause the circuit-breaker to trip unnecessarily, and yet the device should trip in the event of a short-circuit current that could damage the circuit cables.
>
> Type B devices are generally suitable for domestic applications. They may also be used in light commercial applications where switching surges are low or non-existent. Type B devices are designed to trip at fault currents of 3-5 times rated current. For example a 10A device will trip at 30-50A.
>
> Type C devices are the normal choice for commercial and industrial applications where fluorescent lighting, motors etc. are in use. Type C devices are designed to trip at 5-10 times In (50-100A for a 10A device).
>
> Type D devices have more limited applications, normally in Industrial use where high inrush currents may be expected. Examples include large battery charging systems, winding motors, transformers, X-ray machines and some types of discharge lighting. Type D devices are designed to trip at 10-20 times (100-200A for a 10A device).
>
> Normal cable ratings relate to continuous service under specified installation conditions. Cables will, of course, carry higher currents for a short time without suffering permanent damage. Type B and C circuit breakers can generally be selected to achieve tripping times that will protect the circuit conductors against normal surge currents in accordance with BS 7671. This is more difficult to achieve with Type D devices, which may require a lower earth loop impedance (Zs) to achieve tile operating times required by Regulation 413-02-08.

Note that domestic sockets should be protected by Type B devices.

Comment: You should clarify that you can't simply replace a breaker with one rated for more current without upgrading the wiring it is protecting.  The breaker was sized to match the wiring.  A bigger breaker with the same wiring is a fire hazard.

Comment: I thought that was clear enough from the answer. I'll spell it out later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Nicole suggested, the inrush current of your A/C is too high. The breaker does what it is designed for: it protects your wiring from overheating and thus your home from catching fire.

There are some things you can do though.

You can add additional wiring to your A/Cs with additional breakers. This may be very costly but is the safest way to keep things go.

You may change the breaker against a breaker with C or K characteristics but same current rating. Those are resistant to higher inrush currents, which may be sufficient to solve your problem. If it is not your own breaker, talk to the owner or electricity company. However for doing this, your wiring must be flawless. i.e. you need at least 1.5 mm² copper wiring for 16A C or K. 2.5 mm² is better.

You can try to get inrush current limiting devices and mount them next to your A/Cs. Depending on the devices this may or may not work. In any case you should add those limiters to each A/C individually.